# add_theme_support( 'admin-bar' ) causes fatal error

Tags: theme-development, internal-server-error, add-theme-support

I am trying to learn more on Theme Development so I've created my own and everything worked fine except when I added `functions.php` and tried to update it with something simple as:

```
<?php
 add_theme_support('admin-bar', array('menus'));
?>
```

I get `Server 500 ERROR` and I cannot access any part of Wordpress, not even Dashboard. But then as soon as I delete `functions.php` and refresh page my Wordpress is back again and working smooth.

What is so mysterious about `functions.php`????

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 500 is very generic and can be caused by numerous underlying issues. Your first step should be locating error log for your hosting account or asking support to help with that.

My weak guess would be that your file gets created with file permissions that are not secure enough to hosting configuration.

Comment: upon creating file i executed `sudo chmod 777 -R wordpressDirectory` to enable write permissions. you think it has something to do with that??

Comment: btw it is localhost Wordpress configuration that I am running :)))

Comment: @daniel.tosaba it might or might not. As above that is merely first thing I would check if I don't have better idea from error log.

Comment: sorry I am not very skilled with linux file permissions. do you have better number for me so i can quick check it?? many many thanks.

Comment: `[Thu Mar 15 12:28:45 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/daniel/functions.php on line 3, referer: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=%2Fthemes%2Fdaniel%2Ffunctions.php&theme=daniel&dir=theme
[Thu Mar 15 12:28:47 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/daniel/functions.php on line 3`

Comment: so.. i've tried again adding: `add_theme_support('admin-bar',array('menus'));` to it and it updates file without error. but there is no `menus` option under `appearance`. did i get it wrong or using this function i should expect it to be there?? thanks man!!

Comment: @daniel.tosaba I am not sure what you are trying to do there (I don't recognize admin-bar argument) and it's not relevant to error issue this question is about - ask new one about that? On your error issue you should probably enable [`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) to catch errors.

Comment: thanks man. have it all worked out now. appreciate your time&effort on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Your `add_theme_support()` call syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
add_theme_support( $feature, $callback )
```

Where `$feature` = 'admin-bar', and `$callback` = `'callback_function_name'`

Have you defined a callback?

More importantly: **are you absolutely sure you even need to enable Theme support for this feature**? It is only required for *overriding* the default behavior of the admin toolbar.

#### Edit

To add Theme support for navigation menus, you need to add a **separate call** to `add_theme_support()`. **But really**, you *don't need to call `add_theme_support()` directly* for custom navigation menus. Simply call `register_nav_menus()`, and WordPress will handle adding Theme support. e.g.:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary_menu' => 'Primary Menu',
    'footer_menu' => 'Footer Menu'
) );
```

So, putting those together (and properly wrapping them in a callback):

```
function wpse45721_theme_setup() {

    // Add Theme Admin Bar OVerride SUpport
    add_theme_support( 'admin-bar', 'wpse45721_admin_bar_cb' );

    // Add Theme Support For Custom Nav Menus
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary_menu' => 'Primary Menu',
        'footer_menu' => 'Footer Menu'
    ) );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse45721_theme_setup' );

function wpse45721_admin_bar_cb() {
    // What goes here is up to you
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chip!! That is valuable piece of information for future reference. Appreciated!!